# vendor.js file is actually an HTML file? - Ember 2.6 on nginx

Tags: nginx, ember.js

When loading my application I get the WSOD, opening the console shows an error for two JS files:

```
uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < vendor.js
uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < myapp.js
```

Looking at the contents of the files vendor.js and myapp.js in Chromes devtools, their contents are the contents of the `dist/index.html` file, so they're not the actual javascript files (i.e. `dist/assets/vendor.js` and `dist/assets/myapp.js`).

The only way I built the ember application was running the command `ember build`, what would the reason be for seeing an html file in devtools, and is that the actual contents of what the browser sees for the JS file?

I'm using nginx and have checked that it includes /etc/nginx/mime.types, so not sure where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have configured your webserver nginx to always send out the content of the `index.html`. This is necessary because of embers router.

If you visit `http://example.com/myroute` you want to deliver the `index.html` to the browser and let the ember router then render the content for the `myroute` route.

Probably you have configured this wrong, so nginx is *always* sending out the `index.html`, for *every* request, which is not correct. It should only sent out the `index.html` if the requested file is not present.

I hope this leads you to the right direction. This is not an ember issue, just nginx configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue, but found that when I turned the `locationType` option in the Ember CLI `config/environment.js` from `'auto'` to `'hash'` that my pages load correctly without any changes to my server configuration.

Comment: I also realized that when I had a url that was more than one level deep my assets were not being called from the assets folder, but instead from the parent.  For example the file was being served from:

`http:\\www.example.com\example\assets\vendor.js`

This would mean that my Node server didn't realize that it should be serving up the static assets instead of the index.html.  To remedy this I had to change the links to the assets in the index.html file from:

`<script src="assets/vendor.js"></script>`

To:

`<script src="/assets/vendor.js"></script>`

It just needed the slash.